# functional test in playframework fails when adding items to cart

Tags: java, testing, playframework

I wrote a functional test to check adding items to a shopping cart.For a user to be able to add items to cart,he needs to login.So,I created a method to login the user and another method to add the item.Before and after the addtocart method in test,I am checking the size of content of cart.The addtocart functionality works without any problem when I run the app in dev mode(I can check the db too-which is postgres and not an in memory db).The addtocart fails in test.

the controller method which adds item to cart

```
public static void addItemToCart(Long productId,Long cartId,String quantity) {
    Product product = Product.findById(productId);
    ShopCart cart = ShopCart.findById(cartId);
    int qty = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
    CartItem cartItem = new CartItem(product,qty);
    cart.addItem(cartItem);
    cart.save();
    System.out.println("Controller::addItemToCart()::cart id="+cart.id+" has="+cart.cartItems.size()+" items);
}
```

my test method is

```
 @Test
 public void testUserCanAddItemsToCart() {
    Fixtures.loadModels("data.yml");
    User user = User.find("byEmail","user@shop.com").first();
    loginAsCustomer("user@shop.com","userpass");
    ShopCart usercart = new ShopCart(user);
    usercart.save();
    System.out.println("BEFORE ADD::usercart="+usercart.id+" has :"+usercart.cartItems.size()+" items");
    assertTrue(usercart.cartItems.size()==0);
    addItemsToCart(usercart);
    System.out.println("AFTER ADD::usercart="+usercart.id+" has :"+usercart.cartItems.size()+" items");
    assertFalse(usercart.cartItems.size()==0);//why does this fail?

}  

private Response addItemsToCart(ShopCart cart) {
        Product pdt = Product.find("byIsbn","654-0451160522").first();
        assertNotNull(pdt);
        System.out.println("addItemsToCart():BEFORE ADD cart="+cart.id+" has="+cart.cartItems.size());
        Map<String,String> addtocartParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
        addtocartParams.put("cartId", cart.id.toString());
        addtocartParams.put("quantity", "2");
        String addtocarturl = "/items/addtocart/"+pdt.id.toString();
        Response response = POST(addtocarturl,addtocartParams);
        System.out.println("addItemsToCart():AFTER ADD cart="+cart.id+" has="+cart.cartItems.size());
        return response;
    }
```

The console output I get is

```
BEFORE ADD::usercart=48 has :0 items
addItemsToCart():BEFORE ADD cart=48 has=0
Controller::addItemToCart()::cart id=48 has=1 items
addItemsToCart():AFTER ADD cart=48 has=0
AFTER ADD::usercart=48 has :0 items
```

Here, in the controller method,  the cart instance (of id=48) has 1 item after it is saved to db.But in the test method ,the cart instance of same id has 0 content.

I commented out the assertFalse method and retrieved the cart from db using the cartId.Even then the cart of same id has 0 content.I can't understand why this is happening..can anyone shed some light?

//test method body ..modified

```
ShopCart cart = ShopCart.findById(usercart.id);
System.out.println("AFTER ADD::cart="+cart.id+" has :"+cart.cartItems.size()+" items");        
assertFalse(cart.cartItems.size()==0);//why does this fail?
```

Comment: Great question!  This gets at the statefulness of pulling data from the database, so it's potentially very useful for other cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because the cart instance used by your test method and the cart instance used by the `addItemToCart` method are different. Each transaction has its own instance of the entity. And JPA doesn't automagically refresh an entity when some other transaction updates the row mapped by this entity.

You should reload the cart from the database after `addItemsToCart` has been called to check if something has been added to the cart in database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I think I tried that in the last part of the question,by using ShopCart.findById(..).. still it returns an instance with same id but no content!

Comment: Yes, but since you're still in the same transaction, you're re-reading the cart from the first-level cache, and not from database. Try refreshing the cart, or evicting it from the first-level cache and reloading it again. Or use two distinct transactions.

Comment: thanks..that solves it..you gave me a lot to chew upon..thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

I am a slave to object-oriented thinking, so what I'm wondering is, have you thought about making `addItemsToCart()` a method of your `ShopCart` class?  I'm envisioning something like:

```
...
ShopCart usercart = new ShopCart(user);
usercart.addItemsToCart(pdt);
usercart.save();

String addtocarturl = "/items/addtocart/"+pdt.id.toString();
Response response = POST(addtocarturl,addtocartParams);
return response;
```

It's just easier for me to think about making (or retrieving) a `ShopCart` object, modifying it, and putting it in the database.  That's how I would avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and adding JPA.em().clear() in my test before I get the model from the database solved this issue for me.