# How do I test that controllers write correctly to the DB in playframework

Tags: jpa, playframework

I have a FunctionalTest that tests posting to a controller and then does asserts on the model objects to make sure the controller did it's job, like so:

```
@Test
public void editUser(){
    Logger.debug("Edit user test");
    createNewUser();
    final User user = User.<User>findAll().get(0);
    POST("/ManageUser/save", ImmutableMap.of(
            "user.id", user.getId().toString(),
            "user.username", "test",
            "user.email", "test@example.com",
            "user.fullName", "Test Different"
    ));
    User.em().flush(); 
    User.em().clear(); // this is required so that it works on the mem DB
    assertEquals(1, User.findAll().size());
    assertEquals("Test Different", User.<User>findAll().get(0).fullName);
    final User userAfterSave = User.<User>findAll().get(0);
    assertFalse("New user should not be admin.", userAfterSave.isAdmin);
}
```

This passes when I use the mem database

```
%test.db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
```

However if I switch to mysql

```
%test.db=mysql://test:test@localhost/test
```

It fails on the second assert "Failure, expected:`<Test [Differen]t>` but was:`<Test [Tes]t>`". So when using mysql the controller doesn't persist the user properly.

What am I missing here, are there some options for transaction control that I need to change for this to work?

The controller just calls user.merge().save() to update the user, is this somehow wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there are no other users in your MySQL database? This looks like it might be a case of `findAll().get(0)` returning another user than the one you expected. The assertion fails because you *always* expect the *first* element in the `List` to be your test user, which might not be guaranteed.

Comment: @tmbrggmn The assert in the line above is asserting that there is still only one user in the DB.

Comment: Oops, obviously, I missed that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593802/functional-test-in-playframework-fails-when-adding-items-to-cart/9151175#9151175

Answer (score 2):

This is because the mem DB is not properly transactional, meaning the test thread gets new data every read. For mysql however the test thread read the user in createNewUser() meaning it's transaction had the previous version. It's not obvious but POST() starts a new thread with a separate transaction. To solve this swap out

```
User.em().flush(); 
User.em().clear();
```

for

```
JPAPlugin.closeTx(false);
JPAPlugin.startTx(false);
```

The later starts a new transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Do your search in a separate job to be sure it correctly view the modifications (transaction isolation). Here is an example

```
private FeedbackType findFeedbackType(final String name) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    return new Job<FeedbackType>() {
        @Override
        public FeedbackType doJobWithResult() throws Exception {
            return FeedbackType.findByName(name);
        }
    }.now().get();
}
```

This is a private method of my Functional test and I call this method to get my object instead of directly invoking the model

Comment: This lead me to the solution, calling JPAPlugin.closeTx(false); JPAPlugin.startTx(false); instead of flush() and clear() restarts the test threads transaction, letting it read the results of the POST transaction.